# Passing JSON to custom ColdFusion tag

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, custom-tag

I am trying to passing in JSON into a custom tag

My tag looks like

```
<b:column span="{xs=12, md=8}">...
```

When I get around to processing it I want to use:

```
 Myspan = DeserializeJSON(attributes.span);
```

But it just crashes.

[image]

I can use

```
attributes.span     = attributes.span.replacelist('{,=', '{",":');
attributes.span     = attributes.span.replace(', ', ', "', "all");
Myspan              = DeserializeJSON(attributes.span);
```

But this looks like a hack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{xs=12, md=8}` is not JSON, just as the error message indicates.

You probably want that to be `{"xs": 12, "md": 8}`

How are you getting that "JSON" string in the first place? Looks like you might be hand-cranking it - hence it being wrong? If you find yourself hand-crafting JSON strings, you're more than likely going about things wrong, I think. This might be grounds for another S/O question, or perhaps something on codereview..?